# "Groupings" of Option Values: are they actively used?

Tags: custom-fields

When editing an Option Group directly (from Administer / System Settings / Option Groups) (but not when editing the options for a custom field), I can fill in a "Grouping". There is a corresponding column "grouping" in civicrm_option_value.

The grouping isn't displayed when looking at a list of option values in the option group, or when editing a custom field on a contact.

Is there anything that makes use of the grouping within core? I'm encountering a situation in my work where it may be useful, depending on what it actually does (long list of school subjects, grouping by qualification system).

Comment: If you look at civicrm_option_value you will see that some fields 'grouping' is not null. A bunch have 'Avery', and I see some 'Case Status' options are set as 'opened' or 'closed'.
Can't offer any more than that hence adding as 'comment' not 'answer' since i don't feel this adds much to what you already delved in to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Feel free to use it, some other extensions (eg. CiviHR) are using the grouping field as well as the core

```
+-----------+-----+
| grouping  | t   |
+-----------+-----+
| NULL      | 872 |
| Absence   |   3 |
| Avery     |  11 |
| Closed    |   1 |
| Opened    |   2 |
| Timesheet |   9 |
| Vacancy   |  11 |
+-----------+-----+
```